# How to manipulate strings before hsearch

Tags: c

i'm trying to use hash tables from `<search.h>` but i have some difficulties.

In the man, they say hsearch with the FIND action use strcmp to determine if what you search match or not.

Doing

```
add("foo");
find("foo");
```

This code works :

```
void add(char *word) {
    ENTRY e, *ep;
    e.key = word;
    e.data = (int *) 1;
    ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
}

void find(char *word) {
    ENTRY f, *fp;
    f.key = word;
    fp = hsearch(f, FIND);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("This code does not work\n");
    } else {
        printf("This code works\n");
    }
}
```

This one does not

```
void add(char *word) {
    ENTRY e, *ep;

    char newWord[100];
    strcpy(newWord, word);

    e.key = newWord;
    e.data = (int *) 1;
    ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);

    if (strcmp(word, newWord) == 0) {
        printf("According to strcmp, those words are equals\n");
    }
}
```

I must do the strcpy line because I need to convert word into lowercases and I MUST be able to do add("sOmeTHing"). Using malloc I managed to do everything I wanna do, but I'm affraid  I can't free anything...

Would you help me please ? :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to insert "sOmeTHing" and still be able to find it using "something" ? I.e. are you trying to do case-insensitive searching?

Comment: Yup, that's it ! And i would like to understand why the code above, doesn't work.

Comment: There is certainly a problem in the code above but you mention converting to lowercase: I assume you just omitted that from the example or is there more at play?

Comment: Yes i omitted that. Here is the convert_min function
`void convert_min(char s[])
{
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
       if ('A' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'Z')
            s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
    }
}`

But i don't actually used it for the test. I did run the exact code from the topic.

Comment: Here my problem comes from lowercases, but imagine instead i chose to replace the first letter of the word by 'r', i would like to have this working : `add("foo"); find("roo");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to the space of "newWord" beyond its lifetime. Put another way, "newWord" is local to the function "add" which means **it dies when the function returns**. When that happens, the address you stored - `e.key = newWord` becomes dangling.

> Using malloc I managed to do everything I wanna do, but I'm affraid I
>   can't free anything

Using `malloc` is a somewhat sane way to handle this: you need an object that outlives the function.

---

The true solution would be to use an API that allows you to pass your own comparison function. The fact that `hsearch` and friends are specified by POSIX is a small benefit compared to this problem.

The Linux manual does give these "solutions" to freeing memory:

> If these buffers need to be freed (perhaps because the program is
>   repeatedly creating and destroying hash tables, rather than creating a
>   single table whose lifetime matches that of the program), then the
>   program must maintain bookkeeping data structures that allow it to
>   free them.

Comment: Argh, that's very complicated for the purpose of this program.. Too bad. Thank you very much for helping me, cnicutar.

Comment: I have a last question, what is the lifetime of "foo" passed as an argument of add ?

Comment: `foo` itself, i.e. the pointer, is like a normal variable in the function (dies when the function returns). But the object **pointed to** has a different lifetime, depending on how it was declared.